# Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined_NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm facing a problem with the post statement Nodejs and until now I couldn't find the solution 
the error that I get is :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at C:\x\app.js:26:25
```

and the line `app.js:26:25` is this

```
  const name = req.body.name;
```

this is my model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type : String},
    email: {type : String},
    message:{type : String}
});
const contact = mongoose.model("Contact", contactSchema);
module.exports = contact;
```

and this is my `app.post` :

```
app.post("/send", function (req, res) {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const message = req.body.message;

  const add = new contact({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message
  }).save(function (err, data) {
      !err ? res.redirect("/success") : console.log("err");
  });
});
```

this is my html code of the name :

```
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                    <span class="label-input100">Your Name</span>
                    <input class="input100" type="text" id = "name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
```

Any one can help me on this ? 
Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are using Express, but if you are, make sure in your main app file you enable req.body vars:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: thank you it worked, I didn't notice that I deleted that,

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that `req.body` is not set when you go for `req.body.name`. You need a particular middleware setup to get `req.body` populated from form POSTs.

Like so:

```
/*  npm install --save body-parser, cookie-parser  */
/* allow handling json and URL-encoded POST document bodies */
const bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' )
app.use( bodyParser.json() )
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) )
```

And, while you're in the neighborhood make sure you're handling your cookies.

```
const cookieParser = require( 'cookie-parser' )
app.use( cookieParser() )
```